# Generating a basis of the order topology via a dense subset

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering if it is possible to generate a basis for the order topology on a totally ordered set X in the following way if X has a dense subset Z:

We know that the open intervals 
$ \left]a, b\right[$ , $\left]-\infty, b\right[$, $\left]a, \infty\right[$ 
form a basis for the order topology.

Now consider 
$ \left]c, d\right[$ , $\left]-\infty, d\right[$, $\left]c, \infty\right[$ such that $c, d \in Z$.

These are obviously open with respect to the order topology. Since Z is dense in X each element of X is the limit of a sequence of elements in Z. So it should be possible to represent each interval $ \left]a, b\right[$ 
as a union of intervals $ \left]c, d\right[$ such that $c, d \in Z$. And since each open set M can be represented as a union of open intervals
it follows that M can also be represented as a union of intervals where the endpoints are in Z.

It works fine if X is the real line and Z are the rational numbers. I cannot find any sets X where this fails. So is there a flaw in the ideas presented here?

Comment: It is not true that each elmement x has a sequence of points whose limit is x.  D = [0,omega_1) is a dense subset of [0,omega_1]  and no sequence of points from D has a limit of omega_1.  To take that approach you need to use nets.

Comment: Consider $X = \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,1)$ and $Z = X \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. The open interval $(-1,1) = (-1,0]$ in $X$ is not a union of open intervals with irrational endpoints.

Comment: If by $]-\infty,b[$ and $]a,\infty[$ you mean $\{x\in X:x<b\}$  and $\{y\in X: y>a\}$ then your second sentence is correct provided $X$ has more than 1 member or if $X$ is empty. (Note that $X$ might have a largest or smallest member.) If  $X=\{p\}$ then your second sentence is incorrect.

Comment: That is indeed what I mean when I write  $\left]-\infty, b\right[$, $\left]a, \infty\right[$.  So is the statement and my proof correct, when X has more than one member?